# analyzing current and operating settings in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

Is there a way that I can analyze my current settings of my system and my operating system? I'm using Cloudera. Is there a command or can I do everything with the Host Inspector?

Comment: what 'settings'?

Comment: It probably depends on what exactly you are trying to analyze. The Host Inspector gives you some basic information about the things that are important for your cluster's health, but for example if you decide to manage your krb5.conf on your system instead of through the Cloudera Manager you need to check the file on the system whenever you need to check the Kerberos client configuration. What are you trying to do specifically? What can you get already and what information are you missing? In general you won't be able to get all the OS information through the Cloudera Manager.

Comment: I just figured out that I can get setting and operating system information in the Host Inspector

Comment: You can get *some* OS information through the Host Inspector, but not everything. What information are you looking for?